# Dart - Sass @import to inlude css

Tags: import, sass, dart-sass

As per instructions on https://sass-lang.com/install/ I've installed what I believed is dart sass with `choco install sass`. But import of a css file without a .css extension results in an error.

```
@import "/fonts/Lato"
```

error reported

```
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import "/fonts/Lato"
```

The version reported by `sass --version` is  1.69.0 the `Get-Command sass` shows as source `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\sass.exe` so I assume this is dart-sass.

What would be the proper way to include a css file without resulting in css import?

Comment: With dart sass you should use [`@use`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use/) not `@import`